# How to format vector<string> and push_back() into other vectors?

Tags: c++, string, vector, format

Basically the sudo-code I'm trying to figure out how to do is like this:

```
vector<string> lines; // filled by txt file where each line is formatted: "string int"
vector<string> queries;
vector<int> counts;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
    format(lines[i], "%s %d", queries.push_back(%s), queries.push_back(%d));
}
```

I have no clue what function achieves this. I tried `scanf()` and `strtok()`, but ran into problems with both. Is there a better way?

Comment: ok, "incorrect code that gets my point across"?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` and `strtok()` is C, not C++.

In C++, you use `std::istringstream`, and `operator>>`, for example:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string line="apple 42";

std::istringstream i(line);

std::string fruit;
int count;

i >> fruit >> count;

if (i.fail())
{
     // Parsing error, up to you what to do about it.
}
```

Once you have you string, and integer parsed, then you push it into your vectors, as usual.

Comment: How can you put istringstream into a loop if `line` is instead `vector<line>`? It isn't allowing me to redefine it.

Comment: I am not going to guess what you tried to write. Either update this question, or post this as a new question.